# Flashing GApps from Recovery, getting Error Code: 20

Tags: twrp, lineageos, gapps

When I try to flash GApps right after flashing LineageOS with TWRP I get,

```
Updater process ended with ERROR: 20
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/open_gapps-arm64-10.0-micro-20201114.zip
```

What is the cause of this problem, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can't flash Open GApps **right** after flashing LineageOS. You must reboot back into the recovery TWRP, and flash the application after that.

From the [Official Instruction, which support only LineageOS Recovery](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/sailfish/install)

> (Optionally): If you want to install any additional add-ons, **click Advanced, then Reboot to Recovery, then when your device reboots, click Apply Update, then Apply from ADB, then `adb sideload filename.zip`** those packages in sequence.

But this is no different for TWRP. You can find people here in the [bug reports for Open GApps that have the same problem](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/issues/755).